# Consulta sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un detalle.

Habra alguna manera de por ej.
Obtengo unos registros de un select sql server como el de la imagen.

Lo que deseo conseguir es que en la consulta mientras uno de los cuatro registros tenga el valor de NO en la columna Impresa. Aun me siga arrojando los 4 registros. Y que cuando los 4 registros tengan el valor de SI en la columna Impresa entonces que la consulta ya no me arroje los registros.

Mas o menos ha mi parecer es tomarlo como un grupo esos registros y verificar si al menos alguno de ellos tiene el NO en la columna Impresa, entonces que permanezcan mostrandose, hasta que los 4 cambien a SI en la columna impresa, entonces ya no se mostrarian.

No se si me logro explicar, y si hay alguna forma de poder hacer, o alguna sugerencia es bienvenida..

```
select   T.Modelo,  T.CartonLabel,T.DamatrixSerializada,T.L20,  T.L21, T.F40,  T.Z41,  T.Z42,T.N10,  T.CantidadEtiqueta, T.Orden,T.Impresa,Fecha=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T.Fecha,103),
FechaActImpresion=CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()),Sec, Case WHEN Impresa='NO' THEN 'Pendiente por imprimir'
END  as Estatus,  Case WHEN Impresa IS NULL THEN 'Pendiente por imprimir'
END  as Estatus
FROM TablaEtiquetaModelRespaldo17Junio T
WHERE Impresa  in('NO')
AND  Orden='I7760524-14'
--AND Estatus<>'2'
--and L20 LIKE'%L20%'
--and L21 LIKE'%L21%'
GROUP by T.Modelo,T.CartonLabel,T.DamatrixSerializada,T.Fecha,T.Modelo,T.Orden ,T.DamatrixSerializada,T.L20,  T.L21, T.F40,  T.Z41,  T.Z42,T.N10,  T.CantidadEtiqueta, T.Orden,T.Impresa,Sec,Estatus,
Estatus2
ORDER BY
CONVERT(DateTime, T.Fecha,101) asc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dado que tu única etiqueta es SQL Server, creo que no viene al caso hablar de _pantallas_, pues esto está más allá de la base de datos, o bien debieras incluir las etiquetas relevantes para tu pregunta en donde quiera que manejes esas _pantallas_. Si hablamos solo de base de datos, no sé si lo que buscas es que la consulta no te devuelva ningún registro, o qué exactamente.

Comment: No se porque la mayoria de los desarrolladores siempre salen con que es que esto esta de mas..jaja.   Obvio que quiero que me devuelva registros, Son 4 registros en el ejemplo de la imagen, si uno de ellos en la columna impresa cambia su valor  de NO a Si, la consulta aun me debiera de arrojar los mismos registros..  La consulta ya no me debería de arrojar esos mismos registros, ahora si que valga la redundancia hasta que los registros tenga todos valor de SI en la columna impresa..

Comment: Es a lo que me refiero. Si delimitamos a la pregunta a la base de datos, tu quieres que te devuelva registros mientras alguno diga `no` y cuando ya todos tengan `si`, ya no devuelva ninguno, ¿correcto?. Si las respuesta es si, creo que debieras editar tu pregunta, quitar las referencias directas a _pantallas_ y todo lo que no sea base de datos, y mencionar el comportamiento que quieres de la consulta. Eso hará que pueda responderse.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos amigo.  Y si me comprendes, tienes alguna sugerencia de que tal vez que lógica pueda hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas es retornar todas las filas si en un conjunto de datos no se da cierta condición, veamos en primer lugar aquellos 'Orden' que tienen `Impresa = 'NO'`

```
SELECT Orden
       FROM TablaEtiquetaModelRespaldo17Junio
       WHERE Impresa = 'NO'
       GROUP BY Orden
```

La anterior consulta, nos retorna todas las ordenes que al menos tengan un `Impresa = 'NO'`, si todas las filas de una orden fueran `Impresa = 'SI'`, no aparecerían en esta consulta, por lo que la podemos usar para filtrar los casos en tu consulta principal:

```
select   T.Modelo,  
         T.CartonLabel,
         T.DamatrixSerializada,
         T.L20,  
         T.L21, 
         T.F40,  
         T.Z41,  
         T.Z42,
         T.N10,  
         T.CantidadEtiqueta, 
         T.Orden,
         T.Impresa,
         Fecha=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T.Fecha,103),
         FechaActImpresion=CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()),
         Sec, 
         Case WHEN Impresa='NO' THEN 'Pendiente por imprimir' END  as Estatus,  
         Case WHEN Impresa IS NULL THEN 'Pendiente por imprimir' END  as Estatus
         FROM TablaEtiquetaModelRespaldo17Junio T
         WHERE Orden IN (
                    SELECT Orden
                           FROM TablaEtiquetaModelRespaldo17Junio
                           WHERE Impresa = 'NO'
                           GROUP BY Orden
         )
               
         GROUP by T.Modelo,T.CartonLabel,T.DamatrixSerializada,T.Fecha,T.Modelo,T.Orden,
                  T.DamatrixSerializada,T.L20,T.L21,T.F40,T.Z41, 
                  T.Z42,T.N10,T.CantidadEtiqueta,T.Orden,T.Impresa,
                  Sec,Estatus,Estatus2
         ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, T.Fecha,101) asc
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio por la orientacion..